# How to make TFS remember password for power tools?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, credentials, tfs-power-tools

My TFS credentials are different from my windows credentials. To be more precise, here is 
how my credentials look like

*For my workstation*

```
DomainXXX\myname

password
```

*For TFS*

```
DomainYYY\someothername

somepassword
```

---

**The problems**

1. Every time I use the command "tfpt online" in the power tools, it
   prompts me for credentials. There is no "remember me" option.
2. Every time I open a new Visual Studio instance and say 'connect to
   TFS', it prompts for credentials. There is no option to remember /
   save password

**Tried and failed attempts**

I tried adding the TFS credentials in the credential manager of windows. Also added the server name to 'trusted sites' in internet options -> Security settings. These did not solve the original problem.

[image]

Comment: Credential Manager is the place for this; which section did you put it in?  It should be in the "Windows Credentials" section.

Comment: Edward, I have already tried credential manager entry, but to no avail. I had mentioned the same in the original question itself.

Comment: Yes!  I saw that, but it was not clear to me *where* in the credential manager you put it.  Can you take a screenshot maybe?

Comment: Edward, I have added a screenshot to the original question. Basically I entered the credentials in the "Generic Credentials" section

Comment: As @EdwardThomson mentioned, it should be in the Windows Credentials section, which appears to have been disabled. It seems like you'll need to go and talk to your IT administrators and try and get them to allow it.